# for loop running infinitely in release build(visual studio) in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a for loop in one of my projects. Its running infinitely in release build but works fine in debug build. I am clueless. Should I be expecting any memory corruption here?
I have some functions calls in for loop which do not change "j".

```
for( int j=10 ; j>=0 ; j--){

 cout << j << " : " << (j>=0);
 cout << "Entered for loop" << endl;
 func(j);
 ...
 cout << "Exiting the for loop" << endl;
 }
```

Log looks like this:

10 : 1
Entered

Exiting

9:1
Entered

Exiting

.

.

(ommitted)

.

0 : 0
Entered

Exiting

-1 : 0
Entered

Exiting

.

(ommitted)

Comment: This code is ok (well, I wouldn't write it this way, but it is legal). Something nearby is broken. You will need to show the surrounding code. (Remember to trim it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) first.)

Comment: You should post a self-contained, compilable, minimal example of your problem. As it is, it cannot be reproduced in any way, and this question should be closed.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to reproduce the issue with a similar but smaller example.

Comment: Then we are not able to answer. All I can suggest is, use a log file (or just the cout instruction) to print out what's going on step by step.

Comment: So what happens inside the loop? Is the value of `j` changed somewhere, or a pointer to `j` passed to some function?

Comment: Check the break statements in for loop. Also, check if any specific code written under DEBUG macro.

Comment: No. The value of j is passed to function call. Neither it is changed anywhere nor its pointer being passed to any function.

Comment: Note also that some of the functions called in the loop body might contain _another_ loop which is infinite.

Comment: Or do you have any `asserts` in your code? These won't execute in release build. And have you checked that your problem is really the loop, and not a function that is called inside the loop and doesn't return? Output the value of `j` using `printf`/`cout` in each iteration to find out.

Comment: @ajaybidari By replying to us with your explanations of why you code inside the loop "is correct" and why j "is not modified", you are wasting your time. Look at it _in runtime_. Print out what it does. Print out the value of j at the beginning and the end of each loop iteration. Investigate what your code _really does_ when it is executed, not in theory.

Comment: I put logs as above and confirmed..

Comment: `func()` is pass by value or reference?

Comment: Are you even reading my comments? For heaven's sake, print out the value of j in each of your cout statements.

Comment: @koushik It is passed by value.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas I printed value of j and (j>=0).. Both are as exepected but it still runs into infinite loop.

Comment: Apart from the "..." ellipsis, the above code doesn't compile. Show some real code.

Comment: How can it be as expected and _yet_ infinite? This is impossible. Expected is "Entered... 10 Exiting... 10 Entered... 9 Exiting... 9 Entered... 8 Exiting... 8 (...Omitted...) Entered... 1 Exiting... 1 Entered... 0 Exiting... 0" and then no more logs because the freaking loop has been exited. This is expected, and _this_ will not be infinite. What does your log look like? Edit the question with these results, please.

Comment: are you sure your are printing infinite values of j or is it that you are getting blocked and stuck infinitely?

Comment: We are advancing step by step. You added "cout << j << " : " << (j>=0)" before the "Entering" log line. Please add it too before the "Exiting" log line. Please include the full (infinite) results of your log.

Comment: From your latest edit, the (j>=0) _in your log_ "works" correctly, but the one in your for loop doesn't. I don't buy this. _However_, now you could as well copy/paste your "(j>=0)" from the log line to your loop condition, or simply check that "(j>=0)" which is actually working (changing from 1, true, to 0, false) with an "if" in the loop body, and exit your loop with a break statement if it is 0. Of course then you could leave your for as for( int j=10 ; ; j--) because the condition is "not working" anyway...

Answer (score 4):

You have an unsigned integer so it will never go below zero; the step j-- will take you to the largest possible unsigned value when j is zero. So the for loop never terminates.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The problem persists when the variable used in a signed integer.

Comment: "int j=10" doesn't look very unsigned...

Comment: @BoBTFish it was uint32 just now. OP edited to int

Comment: I just changed it to int..